# Setup project modificatios

Tags: c#, sql-server, embed, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have made a application using c# database and sucessfully made a setup projects that outputs setup files needed to install that application but when i install it on other machine first I have to  update installer then framework 2 sp2 and then SQL server and when I tell my client that he would have to do the same he just ........... so I want a way to embed these things in that installer wizard so that in a one go every thing gets installed without prompting for each thing . for example when we install visual studio every thing gets installed without asking permission as we select what to install.so is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a setup wizard for each of the parts you need to install, you may want to take a look at [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), as you can embed those installers in a new one which in turns executes Database/.NET Framework/application setups in correct order to properly configure all the pieces of the solution on a machine.

As setup applications usually have a way to configure options by command line parameters and run silently, you can collect all parameters you need in the new wizard page and call any of the needed installers just by adding a line in the [Run] section of the script.

With Inno you can even embed a pascal script to run code at wizard run-time, for example to inspect destination machine in order to run or not run some installers.  You are able to download required extra-files on demand also.

When you compile a Inno setup project with default options, you get a single executable containing all what you need to install your project, making deployment very easy.

This options may be available for the tool you're using now to produce your installer.